# Trouble publishing/subscribing to a Mongo aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework, publish-subscribe, iron-router

Using Meteor and Iron-Router, I'm trying to publish the following mongo query (in the server folder):

```
Meteor.publish("getTestList", function() {
  return Tests.aggregate(
    [{
      $project : {
        "name" : 1,
        "description" : 1,
        "testNumber" : 1
      }
    }, {
      $sort : {
        "testNumber" : 1
      }
    }
  ])
});
```

Note that I have tested this query in the `meteor mongo` console tool and it works fine there. Also `Tests` is

```
Tests = new Mongo.Collection("tests")
```

and I am subscribing in the router like this:

```
Router.route('/user', {

  waitOn: function() {
    // return [Meteor.subscribe("tests")];
    return [Meteor.subscribe("tests"),Meteor.subscribe("getTestList")];
  },

  action: function() {
    if (!this.ready()) {
      this.render('loading');
    }
    else {
      Session.set("testName", "blablabla")
      Session.set("submitted", false)
      this.layout('BasicLayout')
      this.render('UserPortal')
    }
  }
});
```

And if I navigate to /user then it never gets passed the loading...screen. There are no errors in the console, and if I subscribe only to `tests` and not to `getTestList` (i.e. the commented out line in the code), then the `UserPortal` template does load but I get a console error stating the `Tests.aggregate` does not exist.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meteor does not support aggregation yet. You can get it to work this way though:

Add in an aggregation package: `meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate`

Use `Meteor.call`/`Meteor.methods` instead, since a aggregation result is static at this point. No reactivity supported.

*server side*

```
Meteor.methods({
    "getTestList" : function() {
        return Tests.aggregate(
        [{
            $project : {
            "name" : 1,
            "description" : 1,
            "testNumber" : 1
          }
        }, {
          $sort : {
            "testNumber" : 1
          }
        }
      ])
    }
});
```

Client side:

Your template

```
Template.xx.onCreated(function() {

    Meteor.call("getTestList", function(err, result) {
        Session.set("testlist", result);
    });
});
```

Then you can access the data 'reactively' (when its ready) by checking out  `Session.get("testlist");`

Comment: Having a bit of trouble with this, I need to `{{#each}}` over the session variable, so I've tried `Template.registerHelper("getSessionVariable", function (key) {    return Session.get(key)  });` and then `{{#each getSessionVariable testlist}}` and I've also tried `Template.UserPortal.helpers({ tests: function () { return Session.get("testlist"); }` and `{{#each tests}}` and both ways I'm getting the error (in the console) `Error: Meteor does not currently support objects other than ObjectID as ids`...?

Comment: Apparently this might have something to do with the query returning `_id` fields instead of some other Meteor type `ObjectID`? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/OaX6wOW2mm4. I didn't follow the solution from that thread though, something to do with observeChanges :/

Comment: OK got it working by adding `_id : 0` into the `$project`. Maybe you can add that into your answer? I've realised now that I didn't need to use an `aggregate` for this at all anyway, but the Q/A is still useful for queries that do require aggregation